# "phone manufacturer", "phone producer" or "phone maker"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is more appropriate wording?

Is HTC or Apple a:

- phone manufacturer
- phone producer
- phone maker

I personally would go with manufacturer, but I also see the other ones used. Does it depend on the situation being used or could you generally pick one to be more favorable?

---

*Edit*

I have a section for my website where I list all phones from particular company. What would be an appropriate headline for example.

I checked some sites that already list all phones and found the different wordings, so not sure what is most appropriate. A matter of taste?

Comment: Curiously the three definitions appear to be quite recent according to https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=phone+maker%2Cphone+producer%2Cphone+manufacturer&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cphone%20maker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphone%20producer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphone%20manufacturer%3B%2Cc0. I'd not define Apple or HTC as manufacturers, they do much more, mainly design, software, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I edited where I want to use the wording.

Comment: f.ex. in German I would know which one to go with, even if I could use multiple different words for the same thing

Comment: Do you need to define Apple as a phone manufacturer?

Comment: @Josh61 thanks for your graph. That is helpful :) Yes, I want to list all different company's with their phones in the "phone-section"

Comment: What about writing just the brand?

Comment: They are phone brands.  For the most part they do not directly manufacture, produce, or make anything (other than money).

Comment: wikipedia f.ex. has the [List Of Phone Makers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_makers_by_country)

Comment: Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets mobile communication and media devices, personal computers and portable digital music players, and sells various related software, services, accessories, networking solutions and third-party digital content and applications. http://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/snapshot/snapshot_article.asp?ticker=AAPL

Comment: HTC Corporation researches, designs, manufactures, and sells smart mobile devices; and provides after-sales services worldwide. http://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=8104897

Comment: Thank you @Josh61 for all your comments. I posted an answer based on your comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Usage

As @Josh61 suggested I had a look how frequently the words are used.

So it seems to me that people are using *phone maker* more often in recent times, but as @Josh61 points out as well the companies themselves refer to themselves as  **manufacturer** (amongst other thing).

So by this I can safely assume "manufacturer" is the technical term I was looking for here :)

[by books until 2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=phone+maker%2Cphone+producer%2Cphone+manufacturer&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cphone%20maker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphone%20producer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphone%20manufacturer%3B%2Cc0)

[image: Google Books usage for "phone manufacturer", "phone maker" and "phone producer"]

[by recent searches](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=phone%20manufacturer%2C%20phone%20maker%2C%20phone%20producer&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1)

[image: Google Trends for "phone manufacturer", "phone maker" and "phone producer"]

Comment: That is correct. In tech journalism, those are typically referred to as OEMs, which stands for Original Equipment Manufacturer.